# How can there be a more efficient query than a Left Outer Join

Tags: mysql

I have an app that has an install table, and a use table.

I want to check the install info, and see how many are still active

```
select i.source,count(i.app_id),count(distinct u.app_id) from appinstall i
left outer join appuse u 
on i.app_id = u.app_id
where a.timestamp > '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
and u.timestamp > (last 3 days)
group by i.source
```

Viola, I effectively killed my RDS read replica. Timeout. Gameover

So the problem is both tables are about 1 million rows. The above fields are all indexed. The problem is the distinct and wheres are killing it.

Is it possible to make a query FIRST before the join, and use the data in that? If so - what is it called? Or shall I face it. Using SQL for this no matter what will kill itself - best to just use a webapp or some other engine to hold the data to report?>

Note Innodb, mysql 5.6

Comment: Your OUTER JOIN renders as an INNER JOIN, so, if you're happy that the result set is as you expect, then you may as well write it as an INNER JOIN instead. Beyond that, a covering index on (app_id, timestamp) may well prove more effective- but we'd really need to see the EXPLAIN for the amended query.

Comment: You were right - the where kept causing issue. Combining with schadr's nested slects allowed me to left join them and have seperate data segments :)

Comment: I don't think shadr's solution will be more efficient than a covering index - but I might be wrong

Comment: Note i said the above fields are all indexed - i think you missed that. Assuming covering index is the same?

Comment: No. A covering index is quite different! INDEX(x) INDEX(y) != INDEX(x,y)

Comment: Reading up on now. I have many fields indexed in this, if we index x,y,z,a,b,c,d on a 40 column table, I am curious if it will add much to the inster time. Most the updates to these are done on cron, realtime logs are simple inserts.

Should covering index bea concern?

Comment: Should performance be a concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the where clauses first and cut down your tables using nested selects.

```sql
SELECT i.source, COUNT(i.app_id), COUNT(distinct u.app_id) FROM 
( SELECT i.app_id, i.source FROM appinstall i where i.timestamp > '2015-01-01 00:00:00' ) AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( SELECT u.app_id FROM appuse u WHERE u.timestamp > (last 3 days)) AS u
ON i.app_id = u.app_id
GROUP BY i.source
```

Another approach would be to run explain to see how mysql plans on running the query to see what indexes it uses http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html.

You can also try an inner join and add the missing fields using a union.

Comment: Nested selects did the trick. I could reduce the joins by millions of rows. Thanks!